# Want the Secondary Navigation Bar in squarespace to be at the Bottom - Separate from primary Navigation Bar

Tags: css, customization, margin, navigationbar, squarespace

[SALES PAGE is the secondary navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD1Je.png)
[When turning style into Bottom Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fdw9.png)

I need it be at the bottom of the navigation bar can you tell me what code can I use for it or any styles in squarespace, when I am trying the style option of bottom center it is going at the top on the logo becoming white - (Second Screenshot)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fdw9.png)

Comment: You'll need to share the html markup and css  in order to see what is going on

Comment: Hi, Simon thanks for responding can you help me out where can I find it out?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the location of your link can either be done by editing the HTML & CSS but this will require knowledge of both or can be done in the drag and drop editor by changing the order of the links. If you want a link at the bottom, drag it down the list to be the last one.

https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206543897-Moving-pages-around-your-navigation

Comment: Hi, but I need it to be separate from the primary navigation it is sticked with the others, I dont want to move it around. Example if we just add the margin of the secondary page but there is no option, I dont know much about the CSS so if someone can help me out